# root.sh failed when installing oracle grid 12c infrastructure?

Tags: oracle

I got this error during installing oracle 12c grid infrastructure when run root.sh its failed :

```
CLSRSC-1003: Failed to start resource OC4J
CLSRSC-287: FirstNode configuration failed

Died at /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/crs/install/crsinstall.pm line 2398.
The command '/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/bin/perl -I/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/perl/lib -I/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/crs/install /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/crs/install/rootcrs.pl ' execution failed
```

this is /etc/hosts file :

```
[root@KAASH-HIS-1 log]# cat /etc/hosts 
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1  localhost.localdomain localhost
::1        localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6


#public 

10.93.200.34    kaash-his-1.kaash.local   kaash-his-1 
10.93.200.37    kaash-his-2.kaash.local   kaash-his-2 

#private 

10.93.201.186   kaash-his-1-priv.kaash.local  kaash-his-1-priv
10.93.201.187   kaash-his-2-priv.kaash.local  kaash-his-2-priv

#Virtual
10.93.200.84   kaash-his-1-vip.kaash.local  kaash-his-1-vip 
10.93.200.85   kaash-his-2-vip.kaash.local  kaash-his-2-vip

#SCAN 

10.93.200.81   kaash-scan.kaash.local      kaash-scan
10.93.200.82   kaash-scan.kaash.local      kaash-scan
10.93.200.83   kaash-scan.kaash.local      kaash-scan
```

Also I checked the log file from GRID_HOME

```
[root@KAASH-HIS-1 log]# cat /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/log/oc4j_2023_02_20_13_33_21.err
Feb 20, 2023 1:33:22 PM com.evermind.server.XMLApplicationServerConfig randomizeJtaAdminPassword
INFO: Updating JtaAdmin account
2023-02-20 13:33:23.016 ERROR ServerFile[PersistentMap,/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/persistence/jms.state]: persistence file could not be locked.  Resolve the sharing violation by ending the process currently holding the file lock or by using a different persistence directory for one or both processes.
23/02/20 13:33:23 *** (SEVERE) ServerFile[PersistentMap,/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/persistence/jms.state]: persistence file could not be locked.  Resolve the sharing violation by ending the process currently holding the file lock or by using a different persistence directory for one or both processes.
2023-02-20 13:33:23.018 ERROR Failed to set the internal configuration of the OC4J JMS Server with: XMLJMSServerConfig[file:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/OC4J_DBWLM_config/jms.xml]
23/02/20 13:33:23 *** (SEVERE) Failed to set the internal configuration of the OC4J JMS Server with: XMLJMSServerConfig[file:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/OC4J_DBWLM_config/jms.xml]
2023-02-20 13:33:23.019 ERROR J2EE OJR-00011 Exception starting JMS server: Failed to set the internal configuration of the OC4J JMS Server with: XMLJMSServerConfig[file:/u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/OC4J_DBWLM_config/jms.xml]
2023-02-20 13:33:23.037 ERROR J2EE RMI-00002 Error starting ORMI server KAASH-HIS-1 port 23,792: Address already in use
2023-02-20 13:33:23.038 ERROR java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(PlainSocketImpl.java:521)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:414)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:326)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:192)
    at com.evermind.server.rmi.RMIServer.createServerSocket(RMIServer.java:459)
    at com.evermind.server.rmi.RMIServer.createNonSecureSocket(RMIServer.java:373)
    at com.evermind.server.rmi.RMIServer.setConfig(RMIServer.java:236)
    at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServer.initializeRMI(ApplicationServer.java:2464)
    at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServer.setConfig(ApplicationServer.java:1020)
    at com.evermind.server.ApplicationServerLauncher.run(ApplicationServerLauncher.java:131)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:682)

23/02/20 13:33:23 Error starting ORMI server KAASH-HIS-1 port 23,792: Address already in use
```

error starting ORMI server port 23,792: Address already in use

How to solve this error and continue the setup please ?

UPDATE :

I tried this command :

```
# netstat -anp|grep 23792
tcp6       0      0 :::23792   :::*          LISTEN      12728/java          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:23792 0.0.0.0:* 47463/asm_gen0_+ASM 
udp        0      0 169.254.119.120:23792   0.0.0.0:* 47463/asm_gen0_+ASM
```

the port 23792 used then tried this command :

```
[root@KAASH-HIS-1 install]# ps -ef|grep 12728
grid     12728     1  0 10:11 ?        00:00:55 /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/jdk/bin/java -server -Xms128M -Xmx384M -Djava.awt.headless=true -Ddisable.checkForUpdate=true -Dstdstream.filesize=100 -Dstdstream.filenumber=10 -DTRACING.ENABLED=false -Doracle.wlm.dbwlmlogger.logging.level=INFO -jar /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/oc4j.jar -config /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/OC4J_DBWLM_config/server.xml -properties -ports default-web-site:http:8888,rmi:23792 -out /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/log/oc4j.out -err /u01/app/12.1.0/grid/oc4j/j2ee/home/log/oc4j.err
root     41616 46842  0 21:12 pts/5    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 12728
```

Comment: Are you already running a different version of Grid Infrastructure?

Comment: @pmdba no I run ./runInstaller and this error show on 85% then I tried to run root.sh manually but it is failed , I tried to setup Grid Infrastructure before but it is failed then I de-install it and run the setup again

Answer (score 0):

try these steps :

1- Locate the port number

```
# netstat -anp|grep 23792
```

2- kill the process holding the port :

```
# kill -9 12728
```

3- review /etc/hosts file add the following line :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
```

4- confirm the connectivity between the nodes by using nslookup

5- confirm the DNS and look on file /etc/resolv.conf file

6- review and confirm named service forward and reverse zone file .

7- and finally run the command before start installer

```
./runcluvfy.sh stage -pre crsinst -n node1,node2 -verbose
```